# Style custom TextInputLayout attribut from within theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-support-design, android-custom-attributes

In design library source we can find this line:

```
<declare-styleable name="TextInputLayout">
    <attr format="reference" name="hintTextAppearance"/>
    <attr name="android:hint"/>
    <attr format="boolean" name="errorEnabled"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="errorTextAppearance"/>
    <attr format="boolean" name="counterEnabled"/>
    <attr format="integer" name="counterMaxLength"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="counterTextAppearance"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="counterOverflowTextAppearance"/>
    <attr name="android:textColorHint"/>
    <attr format="boolean" name="hintAnimationEnabled"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

I want to change the color of the error text through errorTextAppearance attribut

I know how to customize it through app:{atribut-name} in the TextInputLayout xml declaration but how can I get to customize one of this attribut from within my theme definition ?

Answer (score 0):

To make it simpler, you have a custom view that holds a set of attributes. To provide values there are three different ways from the bottom (view) to top (application)

1. Provide values to views from attributes or programmatically
2. Create different styles and assign them to this view using `style="@style/MyStyle"`
3. Create an attribute and assign this to the `defStyleAttr` parameter of the constructor of your custom view. And assign a style to this attribute in your theme and Voila!!

For the first two, it is straight forward. Let's concentrate on the last method. There are four steps to achieve this

**Step 1**

Create an attribute (generally in `res/values/attrs.xml` file

```
<resources>
    <attr name="myCustomViewAttr" format="reference" />

    <!-- Below are your set of attributes in declare styleable -->
    <declare-styleable name="TextInputLayout">
       <attr format="reference" name="hintTextAppearance"/>
       <attr name="android:hint"/>
       <attr format="boolean" name="errorEnabled"/>
       <attr format="reference" name="errorTextAppearance"/>
       <attr format="boolean" name="counterEnabled"/>
       <attr format="integer" name="counterMaxLength"/>
       <attr format="reference" name="counterTextAppearance"/>
       <attr format="reference" name="counterOverflowTextAppearance"/>
       <attr name="android:textColorHint"/>
       <attr format="boolean" name="hintAnimationEnabled"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**Step 2**

Using this newly created attribute inside your custom view.

Assuming your custom view's class name is `MyCustomView`. Your class's constructor will look something like this

```
class MyCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.myCustomViewAttr
) : TextInputLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

This will enforce `MyCustomView` to use attributes from `myCustomViewAttr` if nothing is provided for the attributes in the layout.

**Step 3**

Create a style, which is the easiest and used by most of them

```
<style name="Widget.MyApp.MyCustomView" parent="">
   <!-- Assuming you have already defined TextAppearance.MyApp.ErrorText as you required -->
   <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.MyApp.ErrorText</item>
</style>
```

In case, you want to assign some other attribute to your `errorTextAppearance`, then

```
<style name="Widget.MyApp.MyCustomView" parent="">
   <!-- Assuming you have already defined TextAppearance.MyApp.ErrorText as you required -->
   <item name="errorTextAppearance">?attr/myAnotherDefinedAttribute</item>
</style>
```

**Step 4**

Last and final step, assign the style to the attribute

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
   <item name="myCustomViewAttr">@style/Widget.MyApp.MyCustomView</style>
</style>
```

If your text appearance comes from some other attribute, then you can directly assign the attribute

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
   <item name="myCustomViewAttr">?attr/textAppearanceForError</style>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

styles.xml:

```
<style name="TextInputLayout.Error" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Error">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textinput_error_color</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.AppName.TextInputLayout" parent="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/TextInputLayout.Error</item>
</style>
```

in your layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Theme.AppName.TextInputLayout">

                ...
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Also you can add other items from `Widget.Design.TextInputLayout` in `Theme.AppName.TextInputLayout`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. :-)

When I wrote within the theme I am was wondering how to apply this style using an attribut of the theme generalisation. (Without applying a style or attribut to the TextInputLayout directly.)